# Build number using wget in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I want the last build number, either success or failure of a job, in a variable in a Jenkins pipeline. For that I am using:

```
def var = sh 'wget -qO- [jenkinsURL]/job/jobname/lastBuild/buildNumber'
echo "${var}"
```

Echo is returning a value of null value. How do I get the last build number of a job in a variable like `var` so that I can use that variable in a Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

That's the usual way of getting the build ID. I suggest checking the `buildNumber` to make sure it contains a value. Try the below as well.

```
$ build_id=`wget -qO- jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastBuild/buildNumber`
$ echo $build_id
```

However, if you want a different way, you can use the [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). Let's use a [public Jenkins installation](https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/) for an example:

```
curl -s 'https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Precise/view/All%20Precise/api/json?depth=1' | jq -r '.jobs[] | [.lastCompletedBuild.number]
```

The above command should fetch the required details.

I tested the below command and it fetches me the required result.

```
def output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'wget -qO- [jenkinsURL]/job/jobname/lastBuild/buildNumber'
echo "${output}"
```

Comment: In my case curl is not installed i need to get only through wget.
I am coding in pipeline and so ` are not allowed and a syntax error is coming.Please suggest the way to do it in pipeline using wget.

Comment: Have you tried the wget I suggested? Do you still get a null for that too

Comment: $ build_id=`wget -qO- jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastBuild/buildNumber`
$ echo $build_id
giving syntax error in pipeline as ` are not allowed

Comment: Try below.
`wget -qO- jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastBuild/buildNumber > buildID.out && cat buildID.out`

Comment: $ build_id=`wget -qO- jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastBuild/buildNumber`
$ echo $build_id
giving syntax error in pipeline as ` are not allowed
def var = sh 'wget -qO- [jenkinsURL]/job/jobname/lastBuild/buildNumber'
echo "${var}"
gives me
[test2] Running shell script
+ wget -qO- http://jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastBuild/buildNumber
156[Pipeline] }
Although it gives me a value of 156 when i echo it it gives null value.My requirement is to capture this 156 in a variable and use it in the pipeline

Comment: `sh 'wget -qO- [jenkinsURL]/job/jobname/lastBuild/buildNumber > outFile'
lastSBuild = readFile 'outFile'
echo "The Last Successful Build is ${lastSBuild}"`

Comment: Another way would be using returnStdout
`def output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'wget -qO- [jenkinsURL]/job/jobname/lastBuild/buildNumber'`